# Underscores Theme 404.php not displaying?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, underscores-wp

I'm using an _s starter theme for my Wordpress site which is all working fine, except the 404.php template. When I enter a wrong directory I'm getting a generic 404 page (all white with black Times New Roman font displaying "not found")instead of my custom template.

Is there anything I have missed or accidentally deleted in my functions.php?

thanks!

Comment: Did you change/update the path to your 404 page in your config file?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato You don't have to update the path to a 404 file in WordPress, including it as `404.php` in your theme files has WordPress automatically serve the custom 404. Read more about [WordPress Custom 404's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) at the WordPress Codex.

Comment: @user3092791, is the issue only occuring when you attempt to go to `http://www.example.com/test.jpg` or does it also occur when you go to `http://www.example.com/fred`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the error is either Permalink related (go to Settings > Permalink and re-save your settings), or server related in you're rewrites are not correctly setup.

Test to see if your 404 page is showing up with any other theme (twentytwelve for example).